# Remove an observation (record) if it repeats in the variable (column)

Tags: sql, sas

This is my data:

[image]

I like to write a code that removes the second observation (highlighted) IF Var1 repeats AND Var3 is 1. So the my resulting table would look like this:

[image]

Also, these repetitions might pop up in any order. For example, the Var3 can be "1" in the begining, middle, as well as the end of a repetition series.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure you sort your data properly, you could do this (not tested):

```
data want;
  set have;
  sortLast = (Var3 = 1);
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by Var1 sortLast;
run

data want;
  set want;
  if _N_ > 1 then do;
    Var1_lag = lag(Var1);
    if Var1 = Var1_lag and Var3 = 1 then delete;
  end;
  drop sortLast Var1_lag;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you this seems like the most straight forward approach. However, it doesn't seem to remove all the unwanted records. There are still some left for some reason. I might need to add that the number of duplicate attributes in Var1 is not uniform. Sometimes there is only one repetition and sometimes there is more than one.

Comment: Have you tried sorting by Var1 and Var3 before running this data step? (I added the code in my answer)

Comment: Without sorting the variables, I had some 150 records that didn't get deleted. With sorting the records as suggested, I end up with some 500 records not deleted.

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, it will will ignore the observations that appear as as the first observation in a series of repetion AND have Var3=1. In contrast to if the Var3=1 appears after the first appearance of the repetion in Var1. In this case it would delete it.

Comment: It would be easier to see a larger sample of the data but I think I know what's happening. I adjusted my answer to make sure the observations with Var3=1 are below any other (for each group of Var1 values).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep "1" values only when they are the only value for a give `var1`.  If that is correct, one say to do this in SQL is:

```
select t.*
from t
where var3 <> 1 or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.var1 = t.var1 and t2.var3 <> 1);
```

Comment: @Gordon, yes that's correct, I want to keep the "1" only if it is the only value for that given Var1 attribute. However, for me to understand the code, what is t2? Is this referring to a separate table?

Comment: `t2` is a table alias that refers to the table reference in the subquery as opposed to the table reference in the outer query.

Comment: I like to use aliases `inner` and `outer` when doing a correlated sub-query

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the data is sorted by `var1` already, the `var3=1` rows can be simply removed

```
data want;
  set have;
  by var1;
  if var3=1 
     and not (first.var1 and last.var1) /* test for group with more than one row */
  then
    delete;
run;
```